# About optimizing the usage of std::unordered_map

Tags: c++, optimization, hash, unordered-map, bucket

I'm using `std::unordered_map` in case the number of the pairs is fixed at runtime. To get best performance, I decided to rehash it once all the data have been added.

Sample code:

```
class Symbol_t {
   friend struct std::hash<Symbol_t>;
public:
   Symbol_t( uint64_t u ) : v( u ) {};
   inline constexpr bool operator==( const Symbol_t& other ) const noexcept {
      return other.v == v;
   };
private:
   uint64_t v;
}; // class Symbol_t

namespace std {
template <>
struct hash<::Symbol_t> {
   inline size_t operator()( const ::Symbol_t& s ) const noexcept {
      return s.v;  // directly use a uint as the hash value, to avoid collision.
      // instead of return std::hash<uint64_t>()( s.v );
   };
};
}; // namespace std

int main() {
   std::vector<some_struct> vec;
   // preparing data here...

   std::unordered_map<Symbol_t, some_struct> um;
   um.clear();
   um.reserve( vec.size() );
   for ( const auto& data : vec ) {
      Symbol_t symbol( data.id );
      um[symbol] = data;
   }

   um.rehash( um.size() ); // Can this set exactly the number of the buckets?
};
```

My question: Can we be sure that after `um.rehash( um.size() )`, no collision would take place?

BTW:

1. Memory consumption is not a problem, since the number of all pairs is 1000 at most.
2. I've tested and compared `std::map` and `std::unordered_map`, and found that even though with 16~1000 pairs, `std::unordered_map` would still be faster than `map` (and maybe not with few pairs).

Comment: You may well be at the point of diminishing returns there. You can check your `.load_factor` and if you are nowhere close to `.max_load_factor` rehashing isn't going to buy you any additional lookup speed. The most you could get would be a reduction in hash-table size. Rehashing does not guarantee no collisions. That is totally a function of hash modded with number of buckets. Even with only two values and a million buckets you don't guarantee no collisions (the probability is reduced, but no guarantees)

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Because English is not my mother-tongue, maybe I don't get all of your tips. Are you meaning that the probabillity of collision always exists? But my hash func always produce distinct hash-value for every input, so I think that in practic there would be no collision occurs?

Comment: Yes. With a hash-table you will hash your input value and then to determine the index of the bucket for storage you take the modulo of the hash to ensure it fits within your table, e.g. `bucket [hashfn(value) % table_size]`. So increasing the number of buckets (or rehashing) does not guarantee that `hashfn(value) % table_size` will be unique (e.g. not-collide). You could very well have 2 values resolve to the same bucket regardless of the number of buckets you have. The more buckets you have the less chance of collision there is, but it does not eliminate the chance of collision.

Comment: Got it, I tried it out just now. I got many buckets that have more than 2 pairs. Thanks a lot !!!

Comment: Yes, collisions are not bad. In that case your `bucket[]` just holds a pointer to the beginning of a linked-list which is extremely fast to iterate to find the pair needed. Obviously it takes a little more time, but hash-tables are designed to handle collisions efficiently. A couple of very good links to the nitty-gritty are [Coding up a Hash Table](http://www.sparknotes.com/cs/searching/hashtables/section3.rhtml) and [Hash tables - eternally confuzzled](http://eternallyconfuzzled.com/tuts/datastructures/jsw_tut_hashtable.aspx).

Comment: My primary misunderstand is that I don't kown there is a operation %.

Comment: Yes, and the details of how the [`std::unordered_map`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map) is implemented will vary from compiler to compiler, but given that it is a hash-table, in order to map the very long hash value into the limited number of buckets, they all work the same in using `%` to reduce the hash value to a number within the number of buckets available. Pretty cool how it works. Always worth coding one up from scratch to see how it works.

Comment: One of the biggest downsides of std::unordered_map is that it doesn't scale well. When the load-factor starts to increase it means lookup time will increase. The reason for that is that it needs to iterate over the bucket's linked list of colliding elements which means chasing pointers all over the memory. Once that happens you're in trouble. I recently had such a case where lookup performance degraded to ~1% of the maximum perf.